# How to run segbot in Rviz and Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Does anyone know how to run segbot in Rviz and Gazebo from this segbot package(https://github.com/utexas-bwi/segbot)?

I have tried the:

```
$rosrun xacro xacro.py segbot.urdf.xacro > segbot.urdf
```

But it turned out that the segbot.urdf is blank.

Thank you in advance!

Cheers,
Lili

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/105746/how-to-run-segbot-in-rviz-and-gazebo/) by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 286 on 2013-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Lili,

To run something like gmapping inside simulation, you generally don't need to run the robot description directly. Try running the segbot code with autonomous navigation:

```
roslaunch segbot_gazebo segbot_navigation.launch --screen
```

Take a look at the launch file (and how it pulls in other launch files), and you'll figure out how all the nodes are loaded up. You should make a copy of appropriate launch files, and you need to replace the `map_server` and `amcl` nodes with `gmapping`.

Please note 2 other things:

1. gmapping rarely works well in simulation. There are not enough features in the environment, and gmapping messes up when you don't see corners.
2. Try running gmapping with more popular robots like the turtlebot and pr2, as you'll find more help for those robots. Once you have it figured out, try with the segbot code.

In response to your original question about loading the robot model, take a look at this thread: http://answers.ros.org/question/62646/please-help-converting-urdfxacro-to-sdf/

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2013-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on 2013-11-30**:
Hi Piyushk, Thank you for your kind and detailed reply. However, I didn't find the segbot_navigation.launch file in the folder of segbot_gazebo  link: https://github.com/bwi-spring-2013/segbot_simulator/tree/master/segbot_gazebo

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2013-11-30**:
See here: https://github.com/utexas-bwi/segbot_simulator/tree/devel/segbot_gazebo
Note that this will only work out of the box for Hydro, and you will have to do some work in Groovy to get it to work.